# Unable to check checkbox in table cell

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have this table:

```
<iframe title="ManageLegs">
    <table title="Leg Details">
        <tr>
            <th class="headerRow">
                <div>PAX</div>
            </th>
            <th class="headerRow">
                <div>Leg</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</iframe>
```

Accessing the textbox is working fine, but I can´t figure out how to check the checkbox.

I use the following code in my PageObject class:

```
in_iframe(:title => 'ManageLegs') do |frame|
    table(:leg_details, title: 'Leg Details', :frame => frame)
    text_field(:pax) { leg_details_element['1']['PAX'].text_field_element }
    text_field(:aircraft) { leg_details_element['1']['Aircraft'].text_field_element }
    text_field(:show_leg_on_quote_pdf) { leg_details_element['1']['Leg'].checkbox_element }
end
```

Which I am calling like this:

```
on(CharterInquirySavedPage).pax = "2"
on(CharterInquirySavedPage).check_show_leg_on_quote_pdf
```

It is working fine for setting the pax-textbox, but fails when trying to check the checkbox:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `check_show_leg_on_quote_pdf' for #<CharterInquirySavedPage:0x00000004cfd420>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text_field` accessor is for text fields, which are input elements with type "text" and other text-like input fields such as "email".

Inputs of type "checkbox" are considered checkboxes. It is the [`checkbox` accessor](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors#checkbox-instance_method) that creates the `check_` method. In other words, you want the following definition for the checkbox:

```
checkbox(:show_leg_on_quote_pdf) { leg_details_element['1']['Leg'].checkbox_element }
```

Comment: Thanks Justin.
When I change it, I get the following error: Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:index=>0, :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"checkbox"}

Comment: I am having problems reproducing that error. Is the HTML provided the actual table? Given that you are doing `leg_details_element['1']`, I would expect that there would be a cell including "1" in it, otherwise no row would be found.

Comment: Seems I oversimplified the table a little bit, the original one is a real huge beast.
Yes, the line contains a "1". And I can access the :pax textfield in the same line with the given code.

Comment: The value "Leg" is used twice in the table header, and the column with checkbox is the 2nd one, so it always tries to find the checkbox in the wrong column.
I´ve asked developers to make the headers unique.